# kubernetes filebeat disable metrics monitoring

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, filebeat

#### I do not want filebeat to report any metrics to elasticsearch.

Once I start the deamon set I can see the following message:

```
2020-03-17T09:14:59.524Z        INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:118  Starting metrics logging every 30s
```

**How can you disable that?**
Basically what I think I need is `logging.metrics.enabled: false` or is it `monitoring.enabled: false`  ?
I just cannot make it work. I'm not sure where to put it. The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-logging.html) just says to put it into the logging section of my filebeat.yaml. So I added it on the same intendation level as "filebeat.inputs". To no success... - where do I need to put it? Or is it the completely wrong configuration setting I am looking at?

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/beats/master/deploy/kubernetes/filebeat-kubernetes.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: ${NODE_NAME}
            matchers:
            - logs_path:
                logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"

    # To enable hints based autodiscover, remove `filebeat.inputs` configuration and uncomment this:
    #filebeat.autodiscover:
    #  providers:
    #    - type: kubernetes
    #      node: ${NODE_NAME}
    #      hints.enabled: true
    #      hints.default_config:
    #        type: container
    #        paths:
    #          - /var/log/containers/*${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log

    processors:
      - add_cloud_metadata:
      - add_host_metadata:

    cloud.id: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID}
    cloud.auth: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH}

    output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
      username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
      password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}

    logging.metrics.enabled: false
---
```

Answer (score 1):

The `filebeat.yml` is configuration file that mounted at `/etc/filebeat.yml` in the `filebeat` `DaemonSet`.

There are [directory layout](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/directory-layout.html) and [configuration reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-reference-yml.html#filebeat-reference-yml) pages for `FileBeat` in elastic.co documentation.

**Update:**

The `logging.metrics.enabled: false` will only disable internal metrics.
Take a look at this [post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/non-zero-metrics-in-the-last-30s-meaning/173970).

Note the difference between this `INFO` log for the internal metrics:

```
2019-03-26T16:16:02.557Z INFO [monitoring] log/log.go:144 Non-zero metrics in the last 30s
```

And the one in Your case:

```
2020-03-17T09:14:59.524Z        INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:118  Starting metrics logging every 30s
```

Unfortunately this configuration will not stop `FileBeat` from reporting metrics to `ElasticSearch`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I get that. I just can't find the proper place for that configuration setting - or the setting is the wrong one. I updated my question to be more clear about this.